# Excel WorkbookBeforeClose event fired multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of code which i have written in excel vba to control the `On_Close` event of any excel workbook. I have written the code as a Excel add-in and hence it gets loaded for all open excel workbooks.

The objective of the addin to find on close event (rather before close), that if the workbook was saved in a certain path, then it should alert the user with some custom prompts, else do nothing.

The issue is that though the event fires correctly, it fires multiple times (3 mostly) and I cant find the possible reason for this. I have translated the same code in Word VBA and it seems to run fine there.

- I have a standard module: `"savefromtemp"`

*code*

```
Option Explicit

Dim oAppClass As New ThisApplication

Sub Auto_Open()
    Set oAppClass.oApp = Application
End Sub
```

- I have a Class module: `ThisApplication`

*code*

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oApp As Application    

Private Sub oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "abt to close"
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim sFolderName As String, fDialog As FileDialog, ret As Long

    'Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    If InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\SDocuments\") Then
        iRet = MsgBox("Blah Blah Blah. Do you want to save this file to different location?", vbOKCancel, "Alert")

        If iRet = vbOK Then

            Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            ret = fDialog.Show

            If ret <> 0 Then
               sFolderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
               'MsgBox sFolderName
               If sFolderName = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Failed to save. Please check!"
               End If
    '        Else
    '            MsgBox "User pressed cancel"
            End If
            Set fDialog = Nothing

        ElseIf iRet = vbCancel Then

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an observation, but "(3 mostly)" makes me think that it may be firing for each worksheet in the workbook (default is 3). Probably not helpful - but may give you something to look at/for.

Comment: How is `oApp_WorkbookBeforeClose` being called?  Isn't `Workbook_BeforeClose` the standard notation?

Comment: have you tried disabling events? `Application.EnableEvents = False` (then set back to true at the end of your code)

Comment: To commenters who don't recognise this code, it's an `Application` level Event Handler.  A good resource on this is [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Because this is an Application level event handler, when you close the excel application itself, it fires for *all* open workbooks, including any `AddIn`'s.

You will need to test if the closing workbook is one you want to handle

Note: when I tested it, closing a single workbook calls the event only once for me.

Comment: I havn't tested your logic in the event handler (well, only briefly).  It seems to contain other issues, but I guess it's a work in progress.

Comment: Rather than turn this OP into a chameleon question. lets focus on the event firing part first.  Does the answer I gave help?  One thing that may help is to temporarily comment out all code except `MsgBox Wb.FullName` which will tell you which workbook is firing the event. (use `Wb` in your `If` too, not Activeworkbook).  Once you are happy with the event firing, if you are still stuck, ask another question.